# How to use @page CSS in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to use the `@page` css in a Asp.net MVC View (`.cshtml`). Because when I tried, It shows an error message

> the 'page' does not exist in the current context

And the below mentioned is the stylesheet I used in the view

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
            @page port {size: portrait;}
            @page land {size: portrait;}
            @page {
                 size: 85.60mm 53.98mm;
                 margin-top: 8.65mm;
                 margin-bottom: 5.33mm;
                 margin-left: 4.0mm;
                 margin-right: 4.0mm;
                }
        </style>
```

Comment: try with @@ (double)

Comment: @Arvaan Thank You for response, I ll try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Razor use '@' as a special character for scripting language, Try with double @@

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @@page port {size: portrait;}
    @@page land {size: portrait;}
    @@page 
    {
        size: 85.60mm 53.98mm;
        margin-top: 8.65mm;
        margin-bottom: 5.33mm;
        margin-left: 4.0mm;
        margin-right: 4.0mm;
    }
</style>
```